# Transfer data to other sheets/ranges based on dropdown menu on home page

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create an Excel budget sheet for a church. They want to record amounts given to various categories and generate monthly/quarterly reports.

A small team weekly enters tithes and amounts given specifically to any certain category. I built the Excel sheets to do that, but I would like a "home" page that they can enter the information, verify and send to the correct workbook.

Right now this table is on the Home worksheet, Range `B2:J3`.
Row 2 is the headings, data is in row 3.

- The month (January)(`B3`) is selected from a dropdown
- Table range(`C3`) is generated from Vlookup based on month.
- Category (`D3`) is also from a dropdown and is the name of the worksheet the information will go to.

I would like to send Date (`E3`), description (`F3`), From (`G3`), designated (`H3`), and amount (`I3`) (Total range `E3:I3`) to the next available row in the appropriate table, then clear (`F3:J3`) for the next entry, using `J3` as a trigger cell.

Data table:
[image]

This is what I have so far:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 8 And Target.Row = 3 Then
Sub Worksheet_ChangeByVal()
    Dim SourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim DestSheet   As Worksheet
    Dim CopyRange   As Range
    Dim PasteRange  As Range
    
    ' Set the source and destination worksheets
    Set SourceSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Home")
    Set DestSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Home")
    ' Check if the change was made in the dropdown cell
    ' Set the range to copy
    Set CopyRange = SourceSheet.Range("C3:g3")
    
    ' Set the range to paste
    Set PasteRange = DestSheet.Range("f5:j5")
    
    ' Copy and paste the data
    CopyRange.Copy
    PasteRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End Sub
Sub deletemacro()
    Range("e3:j3").ClearContents
End Sub
```

Comment: A few things I can see that are wrong - the main one being the `Sub Worksheet_ChangeByVal()` line.  `Sub` is used to identify the start and name of a procedure.  That procedure must end with an `End Sub` before another procedure can be written.  As it is you're defining a procedure within a procedure - just removing that row will solve that problem in this case.  Next is your `If Target.Column.....` line.  That is the start of a _block if_ statement - the end of the block must be identified with an `End If`.  In this case that is just after the `PasteRange` line (before the first `End Sub`)

Comment: You say cell `J3` is your trigger cell.  `If Target.Column = 8 And Target.Row = 3 Then` is checking which cell has just been changed in the `Worksheet_Change` event.  Column 8 would be looking at cell `H8` rather than `J8`.  You also need to check what it's been changed to otherwise it will run everytime you make a change in that cell - delete the value, write "Hello" in there - it will all fire the procedure.  Maybe something like `If Trim(UCase(Target.Value)) = "Y" Then` as the line after your first `IF` statement and `End If` on the row before the other `End If`.

Comment: Finally, you `deletemacro` will clear the contents in that range on the currently active sheet.  This will include your trigger cell - clearing that will fire the `Worksheet_Change` event.  Start that procedure with `Application.EnableEvents=False` and end it by turning it back to true again.

Comment: Other than that I'm not quite sure what your code is meant to be doing.  Where is the _next available row in the appropriate table_?  At the moment it just seems to be copying `C3:G3` to `F5:J5` in all cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your existing code doesn't compile for a few reasons (eg cannot have a `Sub` within another `Sub`). Try this code which assumes that

- The 'Category' worksheet (in cell D3) already exists
- The 'Range' text (in cell C3) is a valid Range
- The 'y' (or 'Y') entered into cell J3 (which triggers the code) is entered manually (ie by a user typing, not the result of a formula)

The code is commented for your understanding.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' only take action if cell J3 is updated with a "Y" or "y"
    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        If Target.Column = 10 And Target.Row = 3 And StrComp(Target.Value, "y", vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            ' get destination sheet and 'paste range' within that sheet
            Dim DestSheet As Worksheet, PasteRange As Range
            Set DestSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Me.Range("D3").Value)
            Set PasteRange = DestSheet.Range(Me.Range("C3").Value)
            
            ' get next available row within the 'paste range'
            Dim rowNumber As Long
            For rowNumber = PasteRange.Row To PasteRange.Row + PasteRange.Rows.Count
                If IsEmpty(DestSheet.Cells(rowNumber, PasteRange.Column)) Then Exit For
            Next rowNumber
            If rowNumber >= PasteRange.Row + PasteRange.Rows.Count Then
                ' if no such available row, warn user and exit
                MsgBox "No more rows available in sheet " & DestSheet.Name
                Exit Sub
            End If
            
            ' get the range to copy data from
            Dim CopyRange As Range
            Set CopyRange = Me.Range("E3:I3")
            
            ' copy data and clear input area
            With DestSheet
                .Range(.Cells(rowNumber, PasteRange.Column), .Cells(rowNumber, PasteRange.Column + CopyRange.Columns.Count - 1)).Value = CopyRange.Value
            End With
            Me.Range("E3:J3").ClearContents
            
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! I copied the coding over and everything works as far as going to the right sheet, range, and clearing the fields.  However, if I enter a second entry, for the same categorgy, I get the error message "No more rows available"

Comment: The code is expecting the 'Range' (in cell C3) to have multiple rows eg in your example image it is rows 5 to 16 (so allowing for 12 entries to be copied, in that case to the 'Band' worksheet). The code finds the next empty row in that Range ... if there is no empty row within that Range then it shows that warning message ... so if you see the warning message for the second entry then 'Range' is only one row.

Comment: If that's not how you expected the code to operate then please try to clarify?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, John.  What you are saying is exactly what I am wanting,  But I have tried multiple times, checking that the range is E5:J16 as written, but am still getting the error and the program stops.(as it should)  I am willing to share a link to the spreadsheet if you would like.

Comment: Please check that the cells below the E5:J16 range are empty ... no values, no formulas (especially in the left-most column of the range ... in this case, column E)

Comment: Whatever the problem is, seems to be only in the row 5-16 range, (Months Jan, April, July, October) on all the sheets, the other ranges 18-29 and 31-42 are working exactly as they should.  I have double checked, the rows are NOT protected, and the only formatting is a floodfill color and no contents/formulas/hyperlinks....   I Really appreciate your help so far!

Comment: Ranges by month are: Jan (a5:e16), Feb (a18:e29) and March (a31:e42)  The next set of columns are f-j, k-o, and for the last quarter p-t.   I have know Idea why it seems to be only to rows 5-16 that are not working.

Comment: I've revised the code in the answer so that it is now not sensitive to the contents out-with the 'paste range'. Please replace the existing code with this and try it out. Let me know what happens ... if not working then please do share a link to the spreadsheet but you will have to remove all code and save as .xlsx

Comment: That seemed to do it!  Thank you so much for your work, help and patience!

Comment: If I copy this code to another sheet, with different paste ranges (vertically) in the drop down menu, but everything else remains the same, does the code need to be modified?

Comment: Great, glad it worked! If you're happy with the answer to the question, please click on the grey tick/check mark next to my answer. The code should work in another sheet without modification if all else is equal.